# Angular - How disable a field keeping the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good night guys, I have a very simple angular question. I have a form, it has a specific field that I set the value for a patch value but at the same time I need to disable this field. However after the disable, the value is not sent to the back end to be inserted anymore. I've done the test and I saw that only with the patch value, the value is sent normally and inserted in backend normally, but when I disable it, it loses the value and is not sent to the back, I already tried onlyself but I didn't succeed , I would like your help if possible, thanks for your attention. Ah I know that html disable works, but I would like to know if there is any way for me to do this in typescript by disabling the field in the form.

```
 iniciarSituacaoCadastro(){
    if(this.visualizar){
        this.formPesquisar.controls['address'].patchValue(Address.ATIVO);
        this.formPesquisar.controls['address'].disable({onlySelf: true});
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRawValue()` instead of `value`.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue

> getRawValue() retrieves all values regardless of disabled status. The
> value property is the best way to get the value of the group, because
> it excludes disabled controls in the FormGroup.